# How to add BreadCrumbs in my vaadin application?

Tags: java, vaadin

I am developing a vaadin application in which I want to implement bread crumbs. Can any one tell me how to add that functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a breadcrumb add-on for Vaadin already implemented.

Feel free to download it from [add-on directory](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/lexaden-breadcrumb)

Answer (score 3):

What is the problem? they got some information on the website:
https://vaadin.com/web/henrik/wiki/-/wiki/Main/BreadcrumbPattern%3Bjsessionid=DD7DAB31FC7430925021AFBFBC600260

Comment: This link isn't alive

Answer (score 0):

It is more of a backend problem with a front end visualization. You have to create some sort of API that gathers up the steps that you think is relevant and then the UI asks for a representation and prints them out as button or something.

Here's one suggestion for the API for a breadcrumb class out of countless possibilities:

```
public void append(Step)
public void set(List<Step>)
public void clear()
public List<Step> getBreadcrumb()
```

Step would contain a public name shown to the user as well as a method that gets you back to that step.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to create the harness to build the tree of links(buttons): enums, listeners, events. Vaadin's add-on can't handle that out of the box. API doesn't even allow to clean the list of buttons. Good tutorial: [guidance](http://outofrange.ru/2017/12/what-is-wrong-about-vaadin-breadcrumb/)